# Retrofit 2 not sending data when ProGuard is enabled

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, proguard

I try to login my users using Retrofit 2. (Basically a GET to the login URL with a basic header) It works well but once I ProGuard it, the Header Authorization is not sent anymore. (See log outputs)

Sample code :

User Model :

```java
public interface UserService {

    @GET(GET_LOGIN)
    Observable<User> login(@Header("Authorization") String basic);
}
```

Login Activity :

```java
public void onClick(View v) {
    mRetrofit.create(UserService.class)
             .login(Credentials.basic(email, password))
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
             .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
             .subscribe(user -> {
                UserHelper.save(LoginActivity.this, user);
             }, throwable -> Dog.d);
}
```

Proguard File :

```
# Retrofit
-dontwarn retrofit2.** 
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.* <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
    @retrofit.* <methods>;
}
```

Logs (proguard) :

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://passport-supercairos.rhcloud.com/users/login HTTP/1.1
D/OkHttp: User-Agent: VirtualPassport-Client {Android-23} {Aquaris_E5}
D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: max-stale=10800
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized (258ms)
D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 12:57:19 GMT
D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: Express
D/OkHttp: WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Users"
D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/plain
D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1455886639681
D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1455886639787
D/OkHttp: Unauthorized
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (12-byte body)
```

Logs (non-proguard) :

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://passport-supercairos.rhcloud.com/users/login HTTP/1.1
D/OkHttp: User-Agent: VirtualPassport-Client {Android-23} {Aquaris_E5}
D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: max-stale=10800
D/OkHttp: Authorization: Basic ZG9yb2ZyanVAZ21haWwuY29tOmN2dnZ2dnY=
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized (258ms)
D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 12:57:19 GMT
D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: Express
D/OkHttp: WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Users"
D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/plain
D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1455886639681
D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1455886639787
D/OkHttp: Unauthorized
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (12-byte body)
```

Full code can be found here : https://github.com/supercairos/virtual-passport

Comment: I think the main problem is that proguard strip the @Header("Authorization") annotation. But i have no idea why. Especially since I explicitly told him to keep -keepattributes *Annotation*

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work. Here is the proguard configuration regarding Retrofit 2

```
# Retrofit
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
}
```

Thanks @[xudshen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4053022/xudshen)

**UPDATE**

The main problem: I used proguard-android-optimize So I should added:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
```

I also switched back to the regular Retrofit 2 proguard config provided by square :

```
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on RoboVM on iOS. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions
```

Comment: Didn't work for me...still got the same error after trying this and all the other rules i could possibly find.

Linked the rules since it's too long for the comment.
[link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wXa0Y-IWQ34nO7E4DdqFDj9_hXMXkBDXFRcPV9u0Z4c/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Not working, I am still not able to send request parameters

Comment: Yeah me too getting same problem

Answer (score 12):

Adding to @Romain's answer
You Need to add to proguard file

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
```

If you are using @Header, @Query...

Reference from here [Retrofit2 proguard remove param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672922/retrofit2-proguard-remove-param)

Comment: did not worked for me, i am using:
`Call<AssignmentResponse> fetchAssignment(@Query("user") String user);`

Answer (score 11):

finally i find. 
just try this if you use `Gson` ,
add this to retrofit pro-guard :

```
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
```

then use `@SerializedName("name")` in your model .`kotlin` example:

```
class PaymentRequestModel (
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    var name : String = "",
}
```

Comment: I was facing issue in retrofit json parsing. This happened when I change minifyEnabled to true in release build. adding the above in line proguard fixed my issue. Also If you use data class for request body in retrofit post requests, then adding @SerializedName("") is also important.

Comment: i used headers,query,post and body for request and that is not working when proguard is enable can you please tell me what i have to change?

Comment: @Arbaz.in you should add pro-guards of all libraries you are using to your app pro-guard for example retrofit , Gson ,.. .

Answer (score 9):

Another simple solution
use @keep from support annotation
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/Keep.html

```
@Keep
interface APIService 
{

    @GET("/user/auth")
    fun auth(@Header(Constants.AUTHORIZATION) authorization: String): Call<User>

}
```

Answer (score 6):

for me works using annotation @SerializedName

```
public class YourJsonClass{
   @SerializedName("name") String username;

   ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to progaurd

```
-keep public class com.data.YOurDataModels.* {
  public void set*(***);
  public *** get*();
  public protected private *;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Add **@Keep** on your data class

```
 @Keep  
    data class ClassPojo(
      @SerializedName("MESSAGE") val message: String,  
      @SerializedName("STATUS") val status: String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Retrofit 2 compatibility with Proguard code Obfuscator

```
    -dontwarn retrofit.**
    -keep class retrofit.** { *; }
    -keepattributes Signature
    -keepattributes Exceptions
    -dontwarn java.lang.invoke.*
    -keep class com.elephantmobile.ui.remote.model.** { *; }
    -dontwarn retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient
    -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
        @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
    }
    -keepclassmembernames interface * {
        @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
    }
    -dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
 @SerializedName("yourInputParameter")
```

in your bean(model) class for your request body

For example

```
 public class YourClass{
       @SerializedName("yourInputParameter") String yourInputParameter;

       ...
     }
```

it will work

because now **retrofit** unable to read your request body because proguard(minifyEnabled) is true

after adding  **@SerializedName** in your request body it will definitely work for you