# Android - Proguard and retrofit 2?

Tags: android, retrofit, obfuscation, retrofit2, android-proguard

I am using from `Proguard` for my project and bellow code is in my `proguard-rules.pro` :

```
# Retrofit
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.** { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class javax.xml.stream.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.appengine.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.*
-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.**
-dontwarn com.google.appengine.**
-dontwarn java.nio.file.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.**

-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
}
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on RoboVM on iOS. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions

# Add any classes the interact with gson
# the following line is for illustration purposes
-keep class com.example.asheq.zanis_postmans.ListAddressesActivity
-keep class com.example.asheq.zanis_postmans.ListOrderActivity
-keep class com.example.asheq.zanis_postmans.LoginActivity
-keep class com.example.asheq.zanis_postmans.SendReportsActivity
-keep class com.example.asheq.track.TrackLocationService
-keep class com.example.asheq.track.TrackLocationApplication

# Hide warnings about references to newer platforms in the library
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
# don't process support library
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

But when I run my `apk` get me crash :

[image]

And bellow is my gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.asheq.zanis_postmans"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4'
    //compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
    //compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
}
```

Here is my `TrackLocationApplication.class` :

```
public class TrackLocationApplication extends Application {

    private static final String KEY_REQUEST_DATA_NAME = "KEY_REQUEST_DATA_NAME";

    private LocationRequestData locationRequestData;
    private Location startLocation;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //checkAndSetDeviceId();
        checkAndSetUserName();

        if (!retrieveLocationRequestData()) {
            //setLocationRequestData(LocationRequestData.FREQUENCY_MEDIUM);
            setLocationRequestData(LocationRequestData.FREQUENCY_HIGH);
        }
        initializeDB();
    }

    private boolean retrieveLocationRequestData() {
        String name = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString(KEY_REQUEST_DATA_NAME, null);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
            LocationRequestData data = LocationRequestData.valueOf(name);
            if (data != null) {
                locationRequestData = data;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setLocationRequestData(LocationRequestData requestData) {
        locationRequestData = requestData;
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        preferences.edit().putString(KEY_REQUEST_DATA_NAME, requestData.name()).apply();
    }

    public LocationRequestData getLocationRequestData() {
        if (locationRequestData == null) {
            if (!retrieveLocationRequestData()) {
                setLocationRequestData(LocationRequestData.FREQUENCY_HIGH);
            }
        }
        return locationRequestData;
    }

    public Location getStartLocation() {
        return startLocation;
    }

    public void setStartLocation(Location startLocation) {
        this.startLocation = startLocation;
    }

    public LocationRequest createLocationRequest() {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(locationRequestData.getInterval());
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(locationRequestData.getFastestInterval());
        locationRequest.setPriority(locationRequestData.getPriority());
        locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(locationRequestData.getSmallestDisplacement());
        return locationRequest;
    }

//    private void checkAndSetDeviceId() {
//        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(TrackLocationPreferencesManager.getDeviceId(this))) {
//            String deviceId = Utils.getUniqueDeviceId(this);
//            TrackLocationPreferencesManager.setDeviceId(deviceId, this);
//        }
//    }

    private void checkAndSetUserName() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(TrackLocationPreferencesManager.getUserName(this))) {
            String userName = android.os.Build.MODEL;
            TrackLocationPreferencesManager.setUserName(userName, this);
        }
    }

    private void initializeDB() {
        Configuration.Builder configurationBuilder = new Configuration.Builder(this);
        configurationBuilder.addModelClasses(LocationData.class);
        ActiveAndroid.initialize(configurationBuilder.create());
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resolved my problem :

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in C:\Users\asheq\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Retrofit
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.gson.** {public private protected *;}
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.** { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class javax.xml.stream.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.appengine.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.*
-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.**
-dontwarn com.google.appengine.**
-dontwarn java.nio.file.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.**



-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
}
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on RoboVM on iOS. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions



# Add any classes the interact with gson
# the following line is for illustration purposes
-keep class com.example.asheq.zanis_postmans.ListAddressesActivity
-keep class com.example.asheq.zanis_postmans.ListOrderActivity
-keep class com.example.asheq.zanis_postmans.LoginActivity
-keep class com.example.asheq.zanis_postmans.SendReportsActivity
-keep class com.example.asheq.track.TrackLocationService
-keep class com.example.asheq.track.TrackLocationApplication
-keep class com.example.asheq.models.** { *; }



# Hide warnings about references to newer platforms in the library
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
# don't process support library
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.MapActivity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
# To support Enum type of class members
-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }

-keep class com.activeandroid.** { *; }
-keep class com.activeandroid.**.** { *; }
-keep class * extends com.activeandroid.Model
-keep class * extends com.activeandroid.serializer.TypeSerializer

-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }

# Only required if you use AsyncExecutor
-keepclassmembers class * extends org.greenrobot.eventbus.util.ThrowableFailureEvent {
    <init>(java.lang.Throwable);
}
```

Comment: This seems to have a lot of rules that are not related to the issue. Which parts should I use?

Answer (score 39):

YOU need to keep your models, don't obfuscate them. I saw errors with your models, sqlite cannot work on your models. It should be like this:

```
-keep class package.to.yourmodels.** { *; }
```

Comment: only this work for me. i have also tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506111/retrofit-2-not-sending-data-when-proguard-is-enabled/36808211 . but only Roshan Shan solution worked for me

Comment: THANK YOU! I spent too much time to find this problem, but now all fine

Answer (score 12):

## 2021 solution

Use `@keep` annotation before your data classes so they're retained. This removes the need of having separate Proguard rules.

> Denotes that the annotated element should not be removed when the code is minified at build time. This is typically used on methods and classes that are accessed only via reflection so a compiler may think that the code is unused.

```kotlin
@Keep
data class Listing(
    val id: String = "",
    val name: String = ""
)
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/annotation/Keep

Comment: What If I have 100 data classes? Looping over them all at once? Its not logical!

Comment: This works (made it on the body object of the requests&responses), but why does it keep the names of the classes and the field names ? Can't I make them obfuscated ? For example, I see everything identical for `@SerializedName("country") val country: String?` . Can't I at least obfuscate the field name?

Comment: @blueware Indeed this works, but as you said it's quite annoying, and as I've found it doesn't change the names of anything. This is what I've found instead to be working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66670232/878126

Answer (score 5):

Current Proguard rules (as of 12/18) are [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/retrofit2.pro).

```
# Retrofit does reflection on generic parameters. InnerClasses is required to use Signature and
# EnclosingMethod is required to use InnerClasses.
-keepattributes Signature, InnerClasses, EnclosingMethod

# Retain service method parameters when optimizing.
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}

# Ignore annotation used for build tooling.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

# Ignore JSR 305 annotations for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

# Guarded by a NoClassDefFoundError try/catch and only used when on the classpath.
-dontwarn kotlin.Unit

# Top-level functions that can only be used by Kotlin.
-dontwarn retrofit2.-KotlinExtensions
```

Answer (score 4):

***As per rerofit 3.8.1***

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
```

Comment: -dontwarn javax.annotation.**

i was missing this line.. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed that adding the annotation of `@Keep` for each of the classes, indeed it fixes everything, but also doesn't change the names of everything I've set it to.

So, my solution is a bit different:

Put all requests, responses and the classes they need (to hold data) into some folder (or folders if you want to be more organized), and create the Proguard rule inside "proguard-rules.pro" file:

```
-keep,allowobfuscation class com.your_library.rest_objects.** { *; }
```

Alternatively, if this doesn't work for some reason, you can use this (got from [**here**](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Building-your-own-Android-library)) :

```
-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}
```

In addition, if you build an obfuscated library, you should put this (the second one, not the one with "allowobfuscation") in "consumer-rules.pro", and make sure you have this inside its gradle file:

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//        https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library
            consumerProguardFiles 'consumer-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For **retrofit** an **GSON** you need to add below rules in `proguard-rules.pro` file

> For Retrofit Please add below rules

```
# Retrofit
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
}
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on RoboVM on iOS. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform$IOS$MainThreadExecutor
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions
```

> For **GSON** Please add below rules

```
##--- Begin:GSON ----
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

# keep enum so gson can deserialize it
-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class net.mreunionlabs.wob.model.request.** { *; }
-keep class net.mreunionlabs.wob.model.response.** { *; }
-keep class net.mreunionlabs.wob.model.gson.** { *; }
##--- End:GSON ----
##--- End:GSON ----
```