# How to skip proguard models used by retrofit2 that is on the base package?

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, retrofit2

I am writing an application with Kotlin and Retrofit 2. As I use proguard, I follow the rules here:

https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-square-retrofit2.pro

Besides I also need to proguard my models too, as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41136007/3286489

It works fine if I have my models in a package, and I have `-keep class com.elyeproj.wikisearchcount.model.** { *; }`

```
package com.elyeproj.wikisearchcount.model

object Model {
    data class Result(val query: Query)
    data class Query(val searchinfo: SearchInfo)
    data class SearchInfo(val totalhits: Int)
}
```

However, if I keep my Models in the base package as the code below, but I don't want to keep the entire package i.e. `-keep class com.elyeproj.wikisearchcount.** { *; }`, since this defeat the purpose of proguard

```
package com.elyeproj.wikisearchcount

object Model {
    data class Result(val query: Query)
    data class Query(val searchinfo: SearchInfo)
    data class SearchInfo(val totalhits: Int)
}
```

How could I keep my model classes?

I tried `-keep class com.elyeproj.wikisearchcount.Model.** { *; }`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you use the annotation `@SerializedName` and then you don't have to worry about the obfuscation?
You could use the following code:

```
object Model {
    data class Result(@SerializedName("query") val query: Query)
    data class Query(@SerializedName("searchInfo") val searchinfo: SearchInfo)
    data class SearchInfo(@SerializedName("totalhits") val totalhits: Int)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

After exploring further, I found the answer

```
-keep class com.elyeproj.wikisearchcount.Model** { *; }
```

Comment: Instead of this, try with @Jc Miñarro answer.

Answer (score 0):

For people still having this issue... I've had this issue both with Volley + Moshi, and now Retrofit + Gson, though neither was the problem. The real problen is that your model gets obfuscated, which is what you want to prevent. To do so, you have 3 options:


**@SerializedName annotation**
As Jc Miñarro suggested, annotate your parameters with @SerializedName, like so:

```kotlin
data class YourModel(
    @SerializedName("param1") val param1: String
)
```

**@Keep annotation**
Another option, is to use the @Keep annotation when defining your model:

```kotlin
@Keep
data class YourModel(...)
```

**Proguard rule**
Last option is to define your "ignore" rules in your `proguard-rules.pro` file. e.g. to ignore all models in your `/api/models/`:

```
-keep class com.yourapp.api.models.** { *; }
```